# Small form factor PC with socket micro-processor

Tags: mini-pc

I want to build a fast computer but I have little space available to set it in. I don't really need to use a external GPU since I have little demand for graphics power, but I need a fast microprocessor since I will use it for software development.

**Case:**

The case cannot be wider and deeper than 12 cm and no taller than 6 cm. If this proves impossible to find, I can have a little bigger (at most twice on each dimension).

**Processor:**

Any microprocessor that is not soldered to the motherboard with performance similar or higher of an Intel Core i5-6400.

**GPU:**

I don't really have any requirement for the GPU as long as it can drive my Dell 2007fpb with VGA or DVI connecting at the resolution of 1600x1200.

**Memory:**

16 GiB or bigger. Can be any standard like DDR3 or DDR4, DIMM or SO-DIMM (not soldered).

**Hard Drive:**

240 GB or bigger SSD. Must be SATA (not soldered).

**Network:**

Wireless 802.11ac. Not a must have, since I can always buy a USB adapter.

**Cost:**

Under $800.

**Previous research:**

[GIGABYTE GB-BXi5-4570R](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16856164011) is a good candidate but the processor is soldered to the motherboard.

Comment: "A little larger than 12cm x 12cm" is a Nano-ITX mainboard (the board itself is 12x12), which is rarely socketed.  If you can go up to 17x17 for the board, you can go with Mini-ITX, which greatly increases your options.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I found many nano-ITX motherboards that have LGA 1151. Is it possible to fit a Core-i5 with the original cooler inside a nano-ITX case or I would need to buy a thinner cooler?

Comment: @gabrieldiego That's probably dependent on the case.